# Facebook.init failure as3

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, compiler-errors

I updated to the latest facebook api and now it's not working at all.

A simple test which worked previously now throws up the error below :

1061: Call to a possibly undefined method init through a reference with static type Class.

I import the facebook class -

```
import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;
```

I put these in incase as I hoped it may be a class short -

```
import com.facebook.graph.net.*;
import com.facebook.graph.data.*;
```

Application Details :

```
public var APP_ID:String = "My APP ID number";
```

Call facebook with -

```
Facebook.init(APP_ID, onInit);

public function onInit(result:Object, fail:Object):void {                        
    if (result) { //already logged in because of existing session
        trace("onInit, user is logged in");
    } else {
        trace("onInit, user is not logged in");
        //Facebook.login options etc
    }
}
```

I've tried all manner, now with the swc, the source files and still no joy. I resorted to trying the standard api, the desktop and all together and none work. I've searched online and tried numerous interpretations of this and they all throw up the same error regardless of how I try and call it from as3. It seems it's not referencing the facebook files but I'm not 100% sure, or familiar with this error state.

This worked previously and would be grateful if anyone can spot why it throws up the error as for two days now I've tried every combination of everything, including starting from scratch.

Comment: You have the *Facebook.init()* line in a method, right?

Comment: @Fygo, It is. It all worked several days ago till I updated the API but now It won't even compile. I've removed all facebook files and now tried to start from scratch and it just wont do anything other than the error 1061. With SWC or com files!? Any help appreciated to say the least. . .

Comment: That is weird, there is nothing in the code that should do that as far as I see. You are using 1.8.1 of facebook-actionscript-api? That API is archaic, no changes have been made for years so it is difficult to believe something would have been changed. There is no other init() method in your class?

Comment: @Fygo, Nothing to conflict with anywhere. Tested with tutorial material just to ensure safety and the error still happens. What is recommended SWC or com files?

Despite trying both, nothing works however I hope that when it does, to use the safer option, normall I prefer source files but they just throw up the error the same anyway.

Comment: Can you post your files somewhere to take a look? I always use the source files and until now they seemed to work (not counting I changed a few things /JSON parse, etc./)

Comment: @FygoJust removed the folders for the Facbook API 1.8.1, and get exactly the same error as when in my com folder?! Suggests something not initiazing the folder somewhere.

Comment: @Fygo When I type the import command for facebook ie(import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;) it shows the facebook link? Surely this means it's active within the file?

Comment: I rebooted the computer and reinstalled the 1.8.1 swc and managed to get it to work with no errors however it doesn't seem to recieve any callback from the Facebook.init(APP_ID, onInit); I use the same code listed as above but can't get a trace from the function, any idea?

Comment: Does it make the login?

Comment: @Fygo, just recently been able to get it to connect. I used the adobe method via Java as a first stage in seeing if it could connect but still had problems getting it to communicate directly with Flash, which seemed redundant as I was then having to target Java everytime and still wasn't actually able to use as3 with facebook. Recent examples by using the facebook as files all failed with the JSON Multiquery.as bug and I couldn't get passed that and now I tried the swc and it seems to be behaving. Shall update progress as now it seems to connect.